# "javascript:" prefix in an html attribute

Tags: javascript, prefix

I've noticed that some third party libraries use the "javascript:" prefix before a method, in an html variable. I am not an advocate of inline javascript, but am curious to know what it does?

Here is an example:

```
data-permalink="javascript:nRelate.xgeba('meta', 'property', 'og:url')0.content;"
```

I anticipate that the prefix is meant to allow the method call to execute and assign a value dynamically to the attribute, but this piece of test code tells me differently:     http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HxzBa.

Comment: The code does not do anything by itself, it all depend on how it is handled when the time comes

Comment: `javascript:` is the pseudo URI schema and only really has a meaning if the value is treated as "URI". Since the attributes name is "permalink" I guess that's exactly what happens (somehow).

Comment: Consider it the equivalent of `<script>nRelate.xgeba('meta', 'property', 'og:url')0.content;</script>` but in the attribute value context.

Comment: what website is your example from? I'd like to see it in context.

Comment: That's not valid javascript.  A `)` token cannot be immediately followed by `0.content` in any valid javascript program.

Answer (score 2):

The library is probably using that data attribute verbatim as an `href` for an `a` tag. When placed thusly, the code will execute when the link is clicked.

Otherwise, javascript put as the value of `data-*` attributes will not auto-execute.